# Trigger event from frontend in magento

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller

I have created a module with name as (Ownmodule_Autocancel).
In this i added a button to front end at template file named as autocancel/autocancel.phtml.The process is,it should redirect by action controller like "say hiwhn click on it".
But when i click on that button it is not triggered. I don't know how to trigger that here is autocancel.phtml

```
<form method="post" action = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>" id="cancelorder">
<button type ="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Pickup') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::registry('token'); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel Pickup') ?></span></span></button></p>
```

And my controller.php file is

```
<?php
class Ownmodule_Autocancel_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{public function IndexAction(){
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('autocancel'));
//echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/tempete')->setTemplete('autocancel/autocancel.phtml')->toHtml();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

} 
?>

It just show undefined page when click on that button.

Comment: Actually i don't know to create module and this is my firsr. so i need your help

Answer (score 0):

In Template:

```
<form method="post" action = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>" id="cancelorder">
```

Just replace

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>
```

and you should be redirected to the home page.

So if you create another action in you custom controller then, just append to the base url like,

```
echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'/autocancel/CONTROLLER/NEWACTION/';
```

Just read some basic Magento URL routing and u should be up and ready to go.

### UPDATED

Your Class

```
class Ownmodule_Autocancel_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{public function IndexAction(){
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('autocancel'));
//echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/tempete')->setTemplete('autocancel/autocancel.phtml')->toHtml();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

//add another action
public function testAction(){
die('test');
}
```

To reach to this new action in your controller

```
<form method="post" action = "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>/autocancel/index/test" id="cancelorder">
```

Basically you have..

```
MagentoBaseUrl + modulename/controllername/actionname
```

where, modulename = autocancel, controllername = index , action = test .

Hope this helps.

Comment: `onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::registry('token'); ?>')` I just copy this line from some other module. I just want to redirect to my custom module. But how to do this? What i'm asking is like get the url to my controller. but dont know the way for that. and also chek my controller too.